# Angular 2 md-input placeholder not moving up with ngmodel

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using Angular Material to style a input. Usually when there is a value in the input, the placeholder should move up; but it didn't happens when I use ngModel to bind it. However, if I click on the input the placeholder is moving up.

Here is a part of my code :

```
<input mdInput type="text"
       [(ngModel)]="answer.text"
       placeholder="Answer {{i + 1}}"
       [focus]="focus"
       (ngModelChange)="keyPress.emit($event)"
       (keyup.enter)="onEnter.emit()">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem :
I was using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in my component. I used `cd.markForcheck()` on the ngOnInit() function, but I had to move it on the ngAfterViewInit, who is executed after the @Input data (placed on my answer var) is injected in my component.